# How to set log filename in flume

Tags: apache, logging, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

I am using Apache flume for log collection. This is my config file

```
httpagent.sources = http-source
httpagent.sinks = local-file-sink
httpagent.channels = ch3

#Define source properties 

httpagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
httpagent.sources.http-source.channels = ch3
httpagent.sources.http-source.port = 8082


# Local File Sink

httpagent.sinks.local-file-sink.type = file_roll
httpagent.sinks.local-file-sink.channel = ch3
httpagent.sinks.local-file-sink.sink.directory = /home/avinash/log_dir
httpagent.sinks.local-file-sink.sink.rollInterval = 21600

# Channels

httpagent.channels.ch3.type = memory
httpagent.channels.ch3.capacity = 1000
```

My application is working fine.My problem is that in the log_dir the files are using some random number (I guess its timestamp) timestamp as by default.

How to give a proper filename suffix for logfiles ?

Comment: Can you please provide sample logfile name generated and also contents of conf/log4j.properties file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look on the [documentation](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink) it seems there is no parameter for configuring the name of the files that are going to be created. I've gone to the [sources](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/sink/RollingFileSink.java) looking for some *hidden* parameter, but there is no one :)

Going into the details of the implementation, it seems the name of the file is managed by the [`PathManager`](https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/flume-1.6/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/formatter/output/PathManager.java) class:

```
private PathManager pathController;
...
@Override
public Status process() throws EventDeliveryException {
    ...
    if (outputStream == null) {
        File currentFile = pathController.getCurrentFile();
        logger.debug("Opening output stream for file {}", currentFile);
        try {
            outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(currentFile));
    ...
}
```

Which, as you already noticed, is based on the current timestamp (showing the constructor and the next file getter):

```
public PathManager() {
    seriesTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    fileIndex = new AtomicInteger();
}

public File nextFile() {
    currentFile = new File(baseDirectory, seriesTimestamp + "-" + fileIndex.incrementAndGet());
    return currentFile;
}
```

So, I think the only possibility you have is to extend the File Roll sink and override the `process()` method in order to use a custom path controller.

Answer (score -1):

For sources you have execute commands to tail and pre-pend or append details, based on shell scripting. Below is a sample:

```
# Describe/configure the source for tailing file
 httpagent.sources.source.type = exec
 httpagent.sources.source.shell = /bin/bash -c
 httpagent.sources.source.command = tail -F /path/logs/*_details.log
 httpagent.sources.source.restart = true
 httpagent.sources.source.restartThrottle = 1000
 httpagent.sources.source.logStdErr = true
```